# Out of scope variables visible in variable explorer of Spyder 4.0

Tags: python, spyder

I have a main.py which calls a number of functions from multiple python files. When I am debugging the code and inside the scope of a function, all the variables from the main file are visible in the variable explorer. Is there a way to ensure only the variables available inside function scope are visible in the variable explorer?

Comment: Surrounding scope variables *are* in scope, even within functions…

Comment: My understanding has always been that the variables available inside a function are the ones that are explicitly passed in as arguments and any globally declared variables. In the previous version of spyder only the variables that are explicitly passed as arguments would appear in the variable explorer while inside a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to do that at the moment, sorry.

A possible workaround is to prefix the variables in your function (e.g. `a_var1`, `a_var2`, etc) and then filter them in the variable explorer with `a_`, as described in [our docs](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/variableexplorer.html#toolbar-buttons).